# How can I turn Cocoa Auto Layout off for subviews of a NSView programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have looked at the other similar questions, but none of them addressed the question of truly programmatically bypassing Auto Layout for subviews of a `NSView`.

I would need to tell Auto Layout not to layout subviews of a particular `NSView`. I've tried overriding `layout()`, but this only generates a warning and the subview that has no constraints on it (I have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on it, as I don't want any constraints to be automatically generated or otherwise) gets it's frame set to all zero's anyway `[x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0]`. I find it hard to believe that there is no way to tell Auto Layout not to layout a view. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` is not what I am looking for, as I want to disable Auto Layout completely for all subviews of a view. I have two cases where I need this:

1. A note taking app where the user can create and position basic geometric shapes and text views. These are all `NSView` subclasses. I could of course use constraints and manipulate those but what is the point in a view that is not supposed to be adaptive in any way?
2. A math app where I use Auto Layout to layout mathematics on separate lines. I would want to turn Auto Layout momentarily off for the lines that are not beeing edited because as you add more lines and math objects, the autolayout calculation starts to make the app progressively more unresponsive. Since the only thing needing layout calculation is the line the user is editing, the process could be optimized by turning Auto Layout off for the other lines.

Comment: The approach you describe for your note-taking app description isn't optimal. Leaving aside text views, that kind of app generally has just one ``NSView`` view (the canvas). The geometric shapes are simply bezier paths (``NSBezierPath`` instances) that are redraw repeatedly as the user drags them. Have a look at Apple's **Sketch** demo app if you want to see how this is done (it also shows you how to create text that you can move around within the canvas).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have looked at the Sketch demo and did consider that approach too, but for various reasons decided on the NSView-per-object approach. As with pretty much everything, there are pros and cons for every decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want.

Auto layout is ON or OFF for the whole window, not individual views. If any view in the window has had constraints added or is of a class whose `+requiresConstraintBasedLayout` method returns true, then the window uses auto layout.

If you want to use the old way of positioning a view, by setting its frame and its autoresizing mask, then you want `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be true. Indeed, that's the default for programmatically-created views precisely for backward compatibility for auto-layout-unaware code to operate in a window which is otherwise using auto layout. Your rationale for turning it OFF is exactly backwards.

Just leave or turn `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on and have your code take responsibility for setting the view's frame to whatever it desires. Be sure to also set the view's `autoresizingMask` as desired, too, perhaps to `NSViewNotSizable`. You will generally need to deactivate any other constraints on the view for the duration.

If you need to do this for a whole view subhierarchy, then you will have to, well, do it — enable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and set the frame and `autoresizingMask` — for the whole subhierarchy. However, this doesn't seem like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: Thanks Ken. That's what I was afraid of. Auto Layout doesn't seem like a friendly companion ;o) I tried also using ´translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true´ but it throws an exception if a frame is set to a negative width or height. I allowed this because it makes the math easier when the user can draw a rectangle in any direction by dragging. I then just standardize the frame after the user has finished. Doing all that with Auto Layout makes things a lot more complicated for no reason at all. And in the math-app I really need to optimize the Auto Layout process somehow.